# Conditionally return column values from a joined table - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Hi I have a table DataTable as :

```
Name Age Address 
----------------
Tom   21   XYZ
John  23   X123
Sam   32   Y123
```

there is another table MappingTable :

```
Name  Address 
-------------
John  A12345
```

Now I want to create a query that returns the following :

```
Name Age Address 
----------------
Tom   21   XYZ
John  23   A12345
Sam   32   Y123
```

How can I do this. I tried joining the tables but that would replace the complete column. I cannot even use Update since I am only returning a view using this query.

Thanks,
Monica

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select dt.name, 
       dt.age,
       coalesce(mt.address, dt.address)
from DataTable dt
  left join MappingTable mt 
         on mt.Name = dt.Name;
```

Comment: doesnt COALESCE return the first non nullable expression and in our case it will return DataTable value for all. So we wont get MappingTable values